# How to update large amount of rows in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I need to update thousands of rows in a table. For example, I have 1000 rows with ids - 1, 2.. 1000:

```
mytable:
| id   | value1 | value2 |
|  1   |  Null  |  Null  |
|  2   |  Null  |  Null  |
...
| 1000 |  Null  |  Null  |
```

Now I need to change first 10 rows. I can do it like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET value1=42, value2=111 WHERE id=1
...
UPDATE mytable SET value1=42, value2=111 WHERE id=10
```

This requires to many requests and not very fast, so I decide to do this optimization:

```
UPDATE mytable SET value1=42  WHERE id in (1, 2, 3.. 10)
UPDATE mytable SET value2=111 WHERE id in (1, 2, 3.. 10)
```

**Note**: In this case I can actually write `SET value1=42, value2=111` but in real world applications this sets of ids is not the same, for one rows I need to set value1, for other - value2, for some subset of rows I need to set both. Because of that I need two queries.

The problem is that I have very large amount of id's. This queries is something about 1Mb!

**Q1**: Is this a right way to optimize this updates?

**Q2**: Is it right to send queries that is so large? Can I get faster update by dividing this query into several smaller parts?

I can't use `where` statement, I've just have lots of row id's in my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a [TEMPORARY TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) and populate it with your target ids and new values. Then use [UPDATE with FROM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) clause to join to that target and do it in a single command.

In general, whenever you have large numbers of id/values like this life gets easier if you move them into the database first.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**: Is this a right way to optimize this updates?

It should be still possible to write it in one single query using the `CASE ... WHEN` syntactic construct:

```
UPDATE mytable SET
  value1 = 
    CASE 
      WHEN id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 10) THEN 42
      WHEN id IN (11,12,13, 20) THEN 43
      ELSE value1
    END,
  value2 =    
    CASE 
      WHEN id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 10) THEN 42
      WHEN id IN (11,12,13, 20) THEN 43
      ELSE value2
    END;
```

etc.

You mentioned that you may have to update rows in multiple spots, and the above let you do that without problem in one single query.

**Update**: I overlooked the fact that speed was your main concern (you said "optimize"), and my answer is not correct in that regard. Using a temporary table as explained in the chosen answer leads to much better performances.

**Q2**: Is it right to send queries that is so large? Can I get faster update by dividing this query into several smaller parts?

I don't think that Postgresql should have much problems handling a large query (even much larger than 1mb). Remember that SQL DB initialization scripts can be way larger that 1mb.

Comment: This query works 10 hours in my case, but naive approach with many small updates - raw by raw, makes job done in one and half hour.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to test it out: it clearly appears that the temporary table approach is the fastest one in this situation.