# knex.js multiple updates optmised

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

Right now the way I am doing my workflow is like this:

1. get a list of rows from a postgres database (let's say 10.000)
2. for each row I need to call an API endpoint and get a value, so 10.000 values returned from API
3. for each row that I have a value returned I need to update a field in the database. 10.000 rows updated

Right now I am doing a `update` after each API fetch but as you can imagine this isn't the most optimized way.

What other option do I have?

Comment: If you can adapt the API you use in 2, create a request that can take more than 1 value to minimize the number of request.

Comment: Then try to figure if some data are equals, if they do, no need to perform requests that will give you same results

Comment: Thank you for your input, but my question is related to updating the postgres database

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood it :) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875376/how-to-update-large-amount-of-rows-in-postgresql) maybe interest you

Answer (score 0):

Probably bottleneck in that code is fetching the data from API. This trick only allows to send many small queries to DB faster without having to wait roundtrip time between each update.

To do multiple updates in single query you could use common table expressions and pack multiple small queries to single CTE query:

https://runkit.com/embed/uyx5f6vumxfy

```
knex
  .with('firstUpdate', knex.raw('?', [knex('table').update({ colName: 'foo' }).where('id', 1)]))
  .with('secondUpdate', knex.raw('?', [knex('table').update({ colName: 'bar' }).where('id', 2)]))
  .select(1)
```

`knex.raw` trick there is a workaround, since `.with(string, function)` implementation has a bug.